# Meteor - check for errors

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am quite new with meteor; I'm running a project, but when I open the firefox console for errors, I always see errors shown like this:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null  meteor.js:930:11
require<.client.templates.devices["devices.js"]</<@http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=1c0a17f315476c0963550d11831b2b7ad4712f90:1851:2
fireCallbacks/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3398:9
Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744:12
```

For now the project is simple and I know where to check for this error; but with a more complex project, how can I find the correct filename and line where errors occur? Is there a 'developer mode'?

I mean, I can get that the file is `devices.js`,but what about the line? I could have 50 occurences of `document.getElementById` ...

Comment: It's not normal error reporting for Meteor. Which command do you use to run meteor? Does it happen if you create a new app?

Comment: i run a meteor project with the command `meteor`. I simply need to debug a project: if I have errors, I don't get how to check in the code for that errors...